# Android programmatically distinguish between ldpi, mdpi, etc

Tags: android, xml, layout, resolution

I have multiple assets and multiple layouts, but there are some parts of this app where I set width and height dip values within the java code. How do I distinguish between screen sizes here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * sizeInDips` will give you the size in pixels on the current device.

Edit: If you want conditional values based on the configuration, you can do things like:

res/values/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="foo">8dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="foo">16dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

These values can change based on any of the available resource configuration specifiers.

Comment: ah, so I can do conditional statements based on what that equals, okay

Comment: If you need conditional values based on the configuration, you can always use a `dimen` resource. Example added in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

> - xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> - large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> - normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> - small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

AND

[image: Screen size ranges]

From http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html